# How to calculate CPU usage of each HTTP request

Tags: apache, go, cpu-usage

I want to get the CPU usage of each individual request sent to my local Apache server. I am using top to capture the CPU usage but it is not that reliable, because most of the times it captures 0 as CPU usage. I have checked utilities like psutil etc but they did not work?

Is there anyway (some code or package in Go) that can be helpful in this regard?
P.S the best way for me would be if I can't get CPU usage in access.log file?

Comment: Likely because an individual http request takes basically 0 cpu. Normally you just collect the stats in aggregate.

Comment: yeah that is why i was sending many reuests to generate some cpu usage and then divide by the no of requests, but now i cant do that ?i have to get individual  requests as well.. is theer like any hadler thatw e can wrap around a reuest and calculate?

Comment: There's not really a useful 'instantaneous" CPU load, and if you're receiving lots of requests, you're going to be wasting more resources trying to measure the same thing over and over again. What wrong with normal process of recording cpu stats and http requests separately (which can be correlated on demand)?

Comment: that wont give me the desired output, i wont be calculating it daily, ?

Comment: You already mentioned that you were planning on recording the load and dividing by number of requests. You can record the stats at whatever resolution you want, it doesn't have to be daily.

Comment: How does Go relate to a question about apache logs?

Comment: You can see in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) all of the fields available for logging from Apache. CPU usage isn't an option (probably in part because there's no cross-platform way to do this, and partially because it's probably impossible to isolate a single HTTP request for profiling).

Comment: @Flimzy yes i have checked that documentation, i know it is not there, i had an indepth research regarding this, but couldnt find anything, that is why i asked here.. if there is any way? thanks for the reply all..and why negative votes? you could have suggested some other stack website/

Answer (score 4):

The *percentage* (CPU *load*) - no matter how you collect it - will *always* be a point-in-time sample. It's useful for determining what process is using more of the CPU at a given moment, it's useful for profiling a program to see which parts use a greater proportion of CPU over the course of an execution, but it's completely useless for knowing how much CPU a request consumes; that cannot be measured in CPU% at all. Even if you managed to calculate it, "a request uses 5% CPU" is meaningless - does it use 5% for a nanosecond? For an hour? What you want to measure for something like this is CPU *time*: how long the CPU was actively in use by your process.

CPU load is basically calculated as: in the last sample period (say, 1 second), how much of the time was the CPU executing instructions for this process. CPU time is the core of that metric: how much time did the CPU spend executing instructions for this process. That's a metric you can meaningfully use for finding profiling targets for optimization, capacity planning, performance benchmarking, and so on.

The quickest way to get that info would be to restart the service, generate a known level of load (say, 100k requests), check the CPU *time* of the process (e.g. as shown in `top`) at the end, and divide that by the request count. That would tell you how much CPU time a request consumes.

Comment: i do agree with that and that is exactly what i have done until now, but now i had to do the indvidual requests, and after all the research i didnot find anything, so iansked here, thinking maybe there is something that i havenot gotten my hand into.. thanks for the reply.

Comment: You could try doing the same thing to measure the CPU time consumed by handling a single request but there's a reason why people measure by applying heavy load and dividing by the number of requests issued; there can be high variance in handling the same request, so an average is more indicative, plus there's overhead for the parent process that will add more noise relative to a single request than to many requests.

Comment: but it is very difficult to measure using top and other command line tools, i want to check if we can write some code for the same and what direction would that be like?

Comment: @azee: if you're on linux, do what command line tools do and read `/proc/stat`. Implementing that will probably give you a better understanding of what it means to "calculate cpu usage"